# Why shouldn't builder pattern implementations be immutable?

Tags: kotlin, immutability, builder, mutability

Consider the following Kotlin implementation of a string builder:

```kotlin
class StringBuilder {
    private val items = mutableListOf<String>()

    fun append(item: String): StringBuilder {
        items.add(item)
        return this
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return items.joinToString("")
    }
}
```

The internal implementation of the `StringBuilder` requires a mutable list of items, but if you wanted to take immutability seriously, you could easily refactor this to be completely immutable; for example:

```kotlin
class StringBuilder(private val items: List<String> = emptyList()) {

    fun append(item: String): StringBuilder {
        return StringBuilder(items + item)
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return items.joinToString("")
    }
}
```

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), listed under **Disadvantages**

> Builder classes must be mutable.

This clearly isn't the case; as demonstrated, a builder can be designed to be completely immutable, and the fact that this statement is listed under "Disadvantages" would suggest that it would be advantageous for builders to be immutable.

So, I was wondering if there are any specific reasons why builder implementations ***should*** be mutable?

*I could only think of one reason - the garbage collection overhead for an immutable builder will be higher as new instances of the builder have to be returned each time.*

Comment: That wiki article looks like a mess. The C# example is poor because it uses the builder to build a mutable class that doesn't need a builder. I don't see any reason why a builder class must be mutable. Garbage collection is a good reason to use a mutable one *in certain cases*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Disadvantages of the Builder pattern include: [(3)](https://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2010/winter/51023-1/presentations/ricetj_builder.pdf)
>
> - ...
> - Builder classes must be mutable.
> - ...

The [referenced presentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#cite_note-:0-3) in that Wiki for that bullet point does not say "builder classes must be mutable" or list it as a disadvantage. So I find the placement of that reference to be misleading.

I think your point about garbage collection overhead is the only disadvantage in languages like Kotlin? (Aside from the inconvenience of ensuring you deep copy your fields in complex builders)

Answer (score 1):

Your immutable example is the way a builder would be implemented in a pure functional language. As you said though, the issue is all the extra allocations and associated CPU cycles.

Comment: May be worth stressing just how extreme those ‘extra allocations’ would be. Making it immutable would turn every string creation into a quadratic process; e.g. building a 256-char string would allocate at least 32KB (a lot more once you allow for the overhead of alignment, object headers, and wrapper objects). It mounts up fast — building a 32KB string would take more than half a GB of temporary space (and need some serious garbage collection in the process)!

Comment: Why would it? You'd store it in a Lisp-like linked list and add each new item as the head, and only reverse the order when finally building. This has the problem that now calling `toString` on the same `StringBuilder` multiple times is slow, but the mutable implementation in the question has the same problem (though it's easy to fix).